# Finding Δt for a Bezier curve following a certain speed

Tags: functions, bezier-curve

I'm writing an algorithm where I would like a body to move along a Bezier curve at variable speed.

[My bezier curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tjcJ.png)

So I have a Bezier curve which represents a body's X and Y positions over time. Because it's a bezier curve the actual "time" is just a *t* value between 0 and 1.

[The speed function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6AYZ.png)

I have another function called a speed curve, it's another Bezier curve but it could be anything (sum of sines, quadratic, cubic, etc.) which I'm using to get the desired speed at the same *t* value. The details of how I get an actual speed from the Y of that function are irrelevant, it should just be known that they use the same *t* value and that when that function is rising, my body should accelerate.

What I'm struggling with is the following:
Given a fixed time step in *milliseconds*, the speed that was computed for the current *t*, and an rough estimation of the length of the curve called *L*

How do I calculate the *Δt* that represents a jump of position which corresponds to a distance of *timestep* * *speed* ?

I've tried many things, the last of which is
$$
\frac{speed * timestep}{L}
$$

but I end up with a mismatching velocity curve

[Velocity curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Le7GM.png)